# How to batch rename files with two extensions?

Tags: windows, file, cmd, rename, batch-processing

I have a file conversion tool that converts the files correctly but just appends the desired file type extension to the old filename.
So example files are something like
file1.ext1.ext2
.
.
.
fileN.ext1.ext2

I thought it would be an easy fix - just use a wildcard operator on the ren command.
example:
ren \dir*.ext1.ext2 *.ext2

but the output remains .ext1.ext2. I feel like I'm close.

Any suggestions? I've seen suggestions to use push and pop but those seem unnecessary.

Thank you!

Comment: You could use in a command prompt window `for %I in (*.ext1.ext2) do for %J in ("%~nI") do ren "%I" "%~nJ%~xI"` or more safe and better working on FAT32 and exFAT drives `for /F "eol=| delims=" %I in ('dir *.ext1.ext2 /A-D /B 2^>nul') do for %J in ("%~nI") do ren "%I" "%~nJ%~xI"`.

Comment: A file extension is by definition of Microsoft everything in name of a file from last dot to end of name of file. In other words files on Linux starting with a dot to hide it on Linux file systems and not having one more dot like `.htaccess` are interpreted by Windows commands like `for` or `ren` as a file of which name has an empty file name (`%~nI` or `%~n1` expands to an empty string) and the file extension `.htaccess` (string of `%~xI` or `%~x1`). See the MS documentation about [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The * wildcard has a fair bit of compatibility handling related to DOS 8.3 names and whatnot. [How did copying and renaming with wildcards work in MS-DOS?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20210713-00/?p=105433)

One way to get around it is to use full names without wildcards in the rename operation:

```
@echo off

REM test file:
echo.>> "file1.foo.bar"

REM remove foo extension:
for %%A in (*.foo.bar) do for /F "eol=? delims=" %%B in ("%%~dpnA") do @ren "%%~fA" "%%~nB%%~xA"
```

(Change %% to % if not in a batch file)

Comment: Hi Anders, thanks for responding. I'm pretty new to batch scripting.. Could you please break down the last line a bit? /F is file directory, %%A is first loop variable, %%B is second loop variable, what are %%~dpnA, %%~fA, and $$~nB%%~xA?

Comment: First `for` is find files, 2nd `for` is just a string parse so we can access the filename without extension (`%%~nB`). Run `for /?` to read about `~`, n is name, x is extension etc.

Comment: Thank you! I read through it and I think I understand the pieces. How does it know we want .foo removed? Somehow it understands A as .foo and B as .bar? When I ran the script I just changed .foo.bar to the extensions in my situation and kept the rest as-is.

I'm also asking because this is not working for my files. Nothing is happening

Comment: A is the full name, "x.foo.bar". This is the source of the `ren`. Passing %~nA to another `for` means passing in "x.foo" (we removed ".bar" extension) %B="x.foo". %~nB is "x" + %~xA which is ".bar" gives you "x.bar" as the `ren` destination.

Comment: I see! Got it working now - I needed to specify the directory so my (*.foo.bar) just changed to (C:\directory\*.foo.bar). Thanks so much Anders!

Comment: @TonyBalogna Can you share an example of how you solved it? I need a very similar script, to replace *.test.js with *.spec.js. Does it work for you?